# Passing href value to another page using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

As mentioned above, i need to create a `class="donate"` that will be used in anchor tag which will  redirect and pass the value of `href` to my another page i.e -mysite.com/donate.html,

where donate.html will be able to grab that `href` value . 
so that when user click on " continue to download"  will be able to download the
file .

Please let me know whether is it possible or not .
I would prefer HTML and javascript only . as I don't host webpages i use blogger .

I've seen similar concept in templateism.com, something like:

[www.templateism.com/p/preview.html?=www.templateism.com/10/2010/anypost.html](http://www.templateism.com/p/preview.html?=www.templateism.com/10/2010/anypost.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the link like:

```
mysite.com/donate.html?www.yoursite.com.otherpage.html
```

and then using javascript:

```
var href = document.location.href;
var link = href.split('?')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to pass the value you required in querystring like mysite.com/donate.htm?key=value.

On donate.htm page you can use this function mentioned here [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) to fetch the value you supplied in querystring by passing the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript (jQuery required) code below to attach a click event handler to all links with the `donate` class.

**JS on page1.html and page2.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.donate').click(function() {
        // Retrieve the href value and store it in a variable.
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // Redirect a user to the desired page and passes the href value in query string.
        window.location.href = 'http://example.com/donate.html?href=' + href;

        // Ensure the original click event handler is not triggered.
        return false;
    })
});
```

After clicking a link the user will be redirected to the donate page where you can parse the query string and obtain the value of the `href` (which is what was in the `<a href="...">` on the previous page).

There are many ways to parse the query string but the following quick&dirty code should work for you.

**JS on donate.html**

```
var location = document.location.href;
var queryString = location.split('?')[1];

// In the href variable is now what you are looking for.
var href = queryString.substr(5);
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton, if you don't mind can you please give me some small kind of tutorial for this, I'm still beginner . I mean where to add up these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this For example...... This is your html code

```
<a href="http://example.com/donate.html?www.yoursite.com.otherpage.html"></a>
```

As Ashkan said, use his javascript to parse the previous url from it...
Paste this code on donate.html

```
<script>
var href = document.location.href;
var link = href.split('?')[1];
window.location.href = "http://"+link;// This will show you the link
</script>
```

Hope this helps;

Comment: Thanks @ It worked ! and it split the url after '?'  Can you please tell how to redirect the user to that splited url . I mean how to redirect them to 'var link' when they click .

Comment: It redirects to parents directory
actual url :www.myexample.com/rd/donate.html?www.anothersite.com

but it redirects to www.myexample.com/rd/www.anothersite.com 
i need : www.anothersite.com only

Comment: @ShaymMurmu You need to http before the url try my code now. I have updated it.